# Alternative to Rails Single Table Inheritance (STI)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I have a model and table that I believe is perfectly suited to STI. My table is called `Finances` and has two types: Income and Expenses. Besides `type` there are three other columns: `description`, `amount`, and `date`.

I'm getting very nervous using STI in Rails, since it requires some hacking. I'm too new to Rails to hack up the code. Even though it works, I don't understand it. That seems dangerous.

My question is, how do I set up my model, controller, and view if I do NOT use STI? Any best practices to group items in my model? Or do I just do `Finances.where("type = 'Income'")` before setting up a view?

Edit: I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/caser85/5096447) to show the code I'm working with. When I run it I get the error:

```
undefined method `incomes_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc95f60b40>:0x007fbc93883220>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, using STI is standard for Rails, so there is no need to feel nervous. And no need for "hacking".
It has been used very successfully by many developers. And as you have seen, you can find tutorials and general information on the net.

If on the other hand, you decide NOT to use STI, you have the choice of using
(a) completely separate models with their own tables, which will result in *a lot of duplicated code*, or
(b) create you custom "*STI-like*" behaviour by hand. 
The second option could at least be interesting to learn more about Rails.

For example, in your `Finances` model you would define a scope `incomes`, like

```
scope :incomes, where(:type => 'Income')
```

then you can do `Finances.incomes`.

Then, if you have methods that apply only to one of the types, you should check that all records effectively are of the needed type.

Personally, I would advice you to use STI. You get a lot of functionality for free and you are doing it *the Rails way*. 
Imagine, for example, other developers reading your code, they will ask themselves, why you didn't use STI, blame it on ignorance and - if need be - refactor it using STI.

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me to keep pushing forward with STI. I think I have the Model portion down, but am confused when using it in a Controller or View. If you don't mind I would like to post some code on Github later today so you can possibly see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Hey sorry for the zombie post but what do you think @kr1 of polymorphic inheritance? Just for reference I'm making an app with doctors and hospitals, two distinct user groups. Have you used those or is STI still the Rails way?

Answer (score 0):

STI is best if you are using inheritance structure like this. You don't really need to use `Finances.where("type = 'Income'")`. You can simply use `Income.all`. see these posts if they help you.
http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails
http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/

Comment: But what about using form_for? http://henrik.nyh.se/2012/08/rails-sti-and-form-for/ I found on this article I need to use object.becomes to make it work with STI. The author says at the end of the article that this method is fragile so be sure to test it.